# Saving XML file in VB.net aspx web app to a folder

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml, vb.net

I am looking for a solution to the following problem:
 I have a an aspx/vb web application. Users can create some custom content that stored in XML files. I was creating, updating and saving the XML via postback to a folder in the app (not App_Data because I use javascript to read the xml files). Of course this is fine in testing on my machine, but when testing it live on the server, the I get write permission error. I have searched around. Most answers about folder permissions are about trying to give the web app permission to write locally. The few questions that resembled mine stated that it is a security issue to allow the web app to write to a folder other than App_Data. However, this will not work for me because I need JS to read the file. If I have to do a post back just to read the xml from the App_Data, I would have about 5 post-backs to make a selection (the user filters a curriculum document by selecting from a few dropdowns).

Basically, can I give permission to have the VB app write XML files to a web app folder on the server so that the JS can read the XML files? By the way, only authenticated have access to the web app.

The other option would be to save the xml file in the DB, then, on load, write the xml to a hidden div and use JS to read it from there. I don't like that option, as some of these xml file could get large over time. Any guidance would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can set permissions so that you can write to a folder, but it is not the most secure option and I wouldn't recommend it.

I would use a generic handler (ashx file) to serve the contents of the XML files that are stored in App_Data instead. You can then request the individual fies by passing their names or ids through querystring parameters on the handler, such as: `http://localhost/xmlhandler.ashx?name=myxmlfile`

Here's an example of a handler in VB.NET that would serve the XML from App_Data/XMLFolder/:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.IO

Public Class XMLHandler
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
        context.Response.Write(ReadXMLFile())

    End Sub

    Private Function ReadXMLFile() As String
        Try
            Using sr As New StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XMLFolder/" & HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("name") & ".xml"))
                Dim line As String
                line = sr.ReadToEnd()
                Return line
            End Using
        Catch e As Exception
            Return "The xml file could not be read."
        End Try
    End Function

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: I see what this does. The issue will be how can my javascript read the xml files. JS cannot read in the App_Data folder. To prevent a bunch of post backs, I need to use JS Xpath for pulling the needed data from the xml files.

Comment: Your javascript will be reading from the handler instead of trying to access the xml files directly in the App_Data folder. If you put this handler file in the root of your application than your JS code needs to fetch "h ttp://yourdomainhere/xmlhandler.ashx?name=myxmlfile", where "myxmlfile" is the name of the xml file stored in the "~/App_Data/XMLFolder/" folder. In a way this handler is the middleman between your javascript and the files in the app_data folder.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, very new to this. So the above code is a part of the aspx.vb page. Does it need to be initialed or anything on load. I guess I just don't know how it is called. On load?

Comment: No, you need to create a new file of type Generic Handler (file extension .ashx) in Visual Studio and put all of the above code as is in it.

Comment: WORKS! I had to use .ajax to get the xml file. It returns it as a string--not sure if xpath works on a string, but I guess I could convert the string. Will figure it out--the biggest hurdle is over